# Why does LockFile() prevent writes in same thread for remote folders on nas?

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, nas, synology

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour of the c++ WinAPI methods LockFile() and WriteFile() when working on a remote folder of a Synology NAS.
The network setup:

- Windows 10 client
- Synology NAS (RS812)
- Synology NAS (DS1815+)

The RS812 mounts one folder from the DS1815+ as a CIFS remote folder (see https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/FileStation/mountremotevolume ).

When I access this remote folder on the RS812 from the windows client and lock a file in that folder, I cannot write to it anymore from the same thread. I'm very sure that there is no other thread/process accessing the file.

Interesting fact: I can reproduce this using only WinAPI methods - I cannot reproduce it though using a PowerShell script.

This is a c++ googletest where the issue can be observed when setting "tempPath" to a file in that remote folder

```
TEST( FileLockTest, RemoteFolderTest ) {
    auto tempPath = "\\\\nas\\Data\\RemoteFolder\\subfolder\\example.txt";
    if(boost::filesystem::exists(tempPath)) {
        boost::filesystem::remove(tempPath);
    }
    FileLock::Entity ent = CreateFile(tempPath,
                              GENERIC_ALL,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              CREATE_NEW,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                              NULL );
    ASSERT_EQ(0, GetLastError());

    bool hasLock = LockFile( ent, 0, 0, MAXDWORD, MAXDWORD );
    ASSERT_TRUE(hasLock);
    ASSERT_EQ(0, GetLastError());

    char DataBuffer[] = "some example data";
    DWORD bytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    bool success = WriteFile(
                    ent,
                    DataBuffer,
                    bytesToWrite,
                    &bytesWritten,
                    NULL);

    ASSERT_EQ(0, GetLastError());
    ASSERT_TRUE(success);
}
```

The test fails because getLastError() returns the code 33 (ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION) after WriteFile() was called. One can also observe that nothing is written into the file.
The test does not fail when changing the path to a regular folder on the NAS.

This is the PowerShell script that allows to set a file lock and then write into it in that folder. Any hints why this script is behaving differently than my c++ implementation is also welcome!

```
    $path = $args[0]
    if([System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) {
      [System.IO.File]::Delete($path)
    }
    $file = [System.IO.File]::Create($path)

    $file.lock(0, [Int64].MaxValue)

    $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    $text = "Some example text"
    $data = $enc.GetBytes($text) 
    $file.Write($data, 0, $data.length)
    $file.close()
```

Comment: Did you try `LockFileEx`?  Maybe that's what Powershell is using.

Comment: PS Your asserts on GetLastError are unwise.  This, in general, is only changed when a call fails so you might belooking at a stale value.

Comment: Yes, I tried LockFileEx with different flag combinations and get the same behaviour.

Comment: i check - Powershell call exactly `LockFile`

Comment: but when you use `[Int64].MaxValue` really **0** passed to `nNumberOfBytesToLock` - so you not lock any range with this script. use for example `0x0fffffff`

Comment: How do you determine, that the call to `WriteFile` fails? The code you pasted uses the return value of `GetLastError`, without making sure, that that value is actually meaningful. From [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile): *"**If the function fails**, or is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (`FALSE`). To get extended error information, **call the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/d852e148-985c-416f-a5a7-27b6914b45d4) function**."*

Comment: `LockFile(hFile, 0, 0, MAXDWORD, MAXDWORD )` should be ok. It calls `NtLockFile` with `*ByteOffset` of 0 and `*Length` of 2^64 - 1 (fine since FsRtl casts `QuadPart` to `ULONGLONG`). I don't think this lock range can be tested with .NET since [`Lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.lock?view=netframework-4.7.2) is limited to the signed range of an `Int64` (i.e. 2^63 - 1). Also, the PowerShell code in the question has a bug; it should be `$file.lock(0, [Int64]::MaxValue)` (use `::` for a static member). That's why @RbMm saw the value passed as 0.

Comment: I changed the powershell script to do $file.lock(0, [Int64]::MaxValue). Then the close operation fails. If one adds a Flush() call between Write() and Close(), than that call fails (the error message says that another process would lock the file). So with that change, my powershell and c++ code behave same. (Writing fails in that special folder but succeeds in any other folder).